# Nginx CORS doesn't work for POST

Tags: ajax, nginx, cors

I have this configuration in my Nginx

```
server {
    listen       8080;

add_header    Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type';
}
```

Now I have my web application which does `GET` and `POST` for `GET` It works fine but if I do Ajax `POST` I get this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'URL' . Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'Origin' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

If I do a 'GET' request I can see this in my response.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

But if I make a post I don't see any of that.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and got it solve by adding the keyword `always` to my  `add_header` directive. As stated by the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html):

> `add_header`: Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response code equals 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307.
>   [...]
>
> If the `always` parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the response code.

What was happening is that, without `always`, my `GET` request were returned `200` and thus had the expected headers, while my `POST` was getting a 400, thus without the headers and thus triggering CORS errors.

Comment: Worked for me, I suspected my problem was about requests returning 4xx code (the expected behavior here) that got interpreted as CORS errors, but couldn't find more info on that.

Comment: What worked for me :  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' * always;